# Sharepoint 2010 <Status>ERROR_NO_AUTHORIZATION</Status> jquery search,asmx

Tags: 2010, jquery

I have a subsite with unique permissions. Users do not have access to the root, site.

This site has jquery ajax people search which performs a search.asmx. This fails.

even if the path to the _vti_bin/search.asmx

The query result returned is ERROR_NO_AUTHORIZATION

Users can navigate to the _vti_bin/search.asmx

It works if they are added to he visitor group of root site, but I do not want this.

If I add username and password to the ajax request it works again, but is not the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Access to any Web Service in SharePoint must be authenticated (even if you expose your site for Anonymous users), therefore accessing services address is also. Not sure what does "acceptable" means for you, but you might be creating a security breach as search by default it is enforcing Security trimming.

Kerberos could alleviate your need for authentication, as I imagine currently you are running NTLM.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. http://<homesite><subsite>/_vti_bin/search.asmx loads fine for the user. It appears processing the request still requires root access. We are using Kerberos.